# How to find out which ECS cluster is associated to an ALB

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

We run an ECS cluster behind an ELB (ALB, to be specific).

I have a process that allows me to find out which ECS cluster is associated with the ALB by querying the ALB and tracing the results back through the target group and then instances:

---

Here is the bash script:

```
ELB_NAME=$(aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <Zone-ID> | jq -r --arg URL "$URL"'.ResourceRecordSets[]|select(.Name==$URL)|.AliasTarget.DNSName')

ELB_NAME=$(echo $ELB_NAME | cut -f 2- -d "." | rev | cut -f 2- -d "." | rev)

ELB_ARN=$(aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers | jq -r --arg ELB_NAME "$ELB_NAME" '.LoadBalancers[]|select((.DNSName|ascii_downcase)==$ELB_NAME)|.LoadBalancerArn')

TG_ARNS=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-groups | jq -r --arg ELB_ARN "$ELB_ARN" '.TargetGroups[]|select(.LoadBalancerArns[]==$ELB_ARN)|.TG_ARN=$(echo $TG_ARNS | cut -f 1 -d " ")

INSTANCE_ID=$(aws elbv2 describe-target-health --target-group-arn $TG_ARN | jq -r '.TargetHealthDescriptions[].Target.Id' | head -n 1)

CLUSTER=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $INSTANCE_ID | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[]|select(.Key=="aws:cloudformation:stack-name")|.Value' | cut -f 2 -d "-")
```

The problem I have is that when there are no running instances associated with the ECS cluster, I can no longer query them for the the tag that returns the Cloudformation stack name, the request for the targets from the target group is empty.

How can I use the AWS API so that I can determine which ECS cluster the ALB would target if it had running instances?

Comment: It's unclear what "URL" you're interested in. Probably an example and/or what you need it for (=your requirements for it).

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372038/am-i-asking-the-question-wrong-did-i-post-in-the-wrong-community)

Comment: Other formulation are also unclear: 1)what is "Route53 -> ELB -> Instance -> Cluster" -- an API query, your private management interface for your instance? (it's probably what your code does, but the way you wrote it, the code is disconnected from that phrase; it's also unclear where you run that code)

Comment: 2)"get from the ELB to the cluster even when there are no running instances" - what's that supposed to mean? If nothing is running, it has no address.

Comment: 3)"If it were a classic ELB I could have searched for it by looking in the autoscaling groups. I've tried looking for terminated instances in an autoscaling group via cloudtrail but failed." - any illustrations or documentation references? ["failed" is not a problem statement.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: For a general idea what is required in an SO question, (re)read [ask].

Comment: Please ping me if an answer is statisfactionary so I can reward the 50tps - I have no dice in AWS so it would take me some time to _understand_ and _rate_ answers for usefullness.

Comment: @PatrickArtner unfortunately no. It does however show that Ivan is right and I'm horribly unclear. I'll rephrase the question today. Thanks!

Comment: Your edited question unfortunately doesn't add much. As I've explained, you can get the cluster name with the `list-clusters` command. If the cluster is part of a `cloudformation` template, use `aws cloudformation describe-stacks` and/or `aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources` to query for the ECS cluster name.

Comment: Maybe you should explain how all of this is created. Do you have the situation where everything is being created with cloudformation? When you assign `$CLUSTER` in the last line of your code, you populate it with the *cloudformation stack name* **NOT** the *ECS cluster name*. Could be the situation they have the same value, but you should be aware exactly what info you're pulling back

Comment: @arco444 The solution I’m looking for is for when the cluster is empty (for example to start the cluster).

Comment: @Uberhumus looking for *what* when the cluster is empty? And what is your process for "Starting the cluster"? Do you increase the size of an autoscale group?

Comment: @arco444 I'm looking for the cluster that, were it not empty, would be the one to which the load balancer would direct to.

Comment: So, I've rewritten the question. Now I understand the issue. My next question, what created your loadbalancers and how are your services registered? Is the ECS service itself managing this or something external? How much infra is Cloudformation provisioning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177582/discussion-between-uberhumus-and-arco444).

Comment: @arco444 All of our current Load Balancers were created manually.
We started creating a Cloudformation for the infra but it is not yet deployed.
It will be, so ideally a solution will solve for both.
Is the ECS service managing what?

Comment: @PatrickArtner the checked answer solves it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not really clear what you're asking for, or indeed the purpose you are trying to achieve, but the following should set you on the right track.

An ECS "cluster" is really just an Amazon service, when you create a cluster nothing is really provisioned. You can think of an empty cluster as a record or a placeholder in the ECS service.

In order to do anything with a cluster, it needs instances. When you boot an EC2 machine from a supported AMI, appropriate IAM role and the cluster name written to a config file, the instance will join the cluster. (If you create a cluster via the AWS console, a CloudFormation template is created that handles the provisioning and orchestration of these steps.) The ECS cluster management can then schedule tasks and services onto that instance as you have defined in the ECS service.

Without any instances, there can be no listening containers, therefore there can be no target groups in your ALB that route to anything. So it is not possible to `get from the ELB to the cluster...` as you have asked when there are no running instances.

You might find the following commands are a better way of determining whether or not you have a running cluster.

First, use the `list-clusters` command to show which clusters are available:

```
aws ecs list-clusters 
{
    "clusterArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXX:cluster/your_cluster"
    ]
}
```

Then use the output from that to show if there are any EC2 instances registered to the cluster:

```
aws ecs describe-clusters --clusters your_cluster
{
    "clusters": [
        {
            "status": "ACTIVE", 
            "statistics": [], 
            "clusterName": "your_cluster", 
            "registeredContainerInstancesCount": 1, 
            "pendingTasksCount": 0, 
            "runningTasksCount": 0, 
            "activeServicesCount": 0, 
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXX:cluster/your_cluster"
        }
    ], 
    "failures": []
}
```

Note the `registeredContainerInstancesCount` property shows the number of running instances. I assume you have your ECS services set to register tasks (containers) with the ALB, so when the count is greater than `0`, this will be possible.

So, querying that property should tell you if your cluster is "**on**" or not:

```
if [[ $(aws ecs describe-clusters --clusters your_cluster | jq -r '.clusters[].registeredContainerInstancesCount') -gt 0 ]] ; then 
  echo "cluster is on"
else 
  echo "cluster is off"
fi
```